# How can I use my DLL in other computer?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, windows-10, dependency-management

I developed a dll project with opencv and tesseract then I use it in C# WCF service project via CLR. When I try to import my dll in other computer, It give dependency error. 
In my opinion, this error depends on used opencv and tesseract libs in dll. So how can I solve this issue ? I want to use this dll in other machines.

Comment: You ship the opencv and tesseract dll's too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) utility to understand what dlls you should deliver with your application to the other computer.

On the other computer with this utility you can understand what dlls are missed.

You should inspect dependencies not only for your application, but also for OpenCV and Tesseract. These dlls dependent of *MS VS Redistributable* dlls which could also be missed on the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it is best to create a setup for your installation containing all dependent DLL's

There are several free programs that make it simple to create a setup if you do not want to use the built in one in Visual Studio e.g. [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)